# How to use JavaScript to handle complex 100 digits (+/-) times 100 digits (+/-) multiplication without having an overflow error?

Tags: javascript, bigint

When I tried BigInt, the result returned a wrong result:

```
BigInt(123456789123456789*111111111111)
13717421013703702653171662848n
```

And this is what the actual result should be like by hand-written calculation:

```
13717421013703703578986282579
```

Is there a way to produce the correct result without this error? Thank you.

Comment: `BigInt("123456789123456789") * BigInt("111111111111")` or `123456789123456789n * 111111111111n`. `123456789123456789 * 111111111111` just results in a regular, imprecise number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the *multiplication* to `BigInt`, convert both numbers to BigInt and multiply them after that:

```js
const big = 123456789123456789n * 111111111111n;
console.log(big)
```

Note, use your browser's console, not the snippet's one (also, this won't work in Safari).

Comment: You could add a `toLocaleString`, if you need the full string version / grouped version of the number.
> (123456789123456789n*111111111111n).toLocaleString('fullwide', {useGrouping:false})